# Tikz - how to add labels to existing paths created by `graphs`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to add a few labels to paths but I cannot work out coordinates of the existing paths which has already been created using `graphs` and `matrix`. I found a workaround in which I hardcoded the coordinates and add new labels. The code below is a MWE and the labels I added later are after the comment "New labels" (see code below).

The problem is this will break if I change angles `out=XXX`, `in=XXX`, and `looseness=XXX`. I have been looking around to see if the coordinates can be established from existing nodes.

Thanks

This is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows.meta,
    calc,
    graphs,
    matrix,
    positioning,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (bn) [matrix of nodes, column sep=14mm, row sep=1mm, nodes={draw, circle, fill=white, very thick, minimum width=8mm}]
  {
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=30, in=155}] {
    (bn-1-1) -> (bn-1-2) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-8)
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=210, in=335}] {
    (bn-1-8) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-2) -> (bn-1-1)
  };
  \foreach \x in {1,...,8}
    \path[->,>=Latex]
      (bn-1-\x) edge [out=110,in=70,looseness=12] node[above] {} (bn-1-\x);

  % New labels
  \node (pnq) at ([yshift=7.5mm]$(bn-1-3)!0.5!(bn-1-4)$) {$p(1-q)$};
  \node (npq) at ([yshift=-7.5mm]$(bn-1-3)!0.5!(bn-1-2)$) {$q(1-p)$};
  \node (npq) at ([yshift=16.5mm]$(bn-1-3)!0.5!(bn-1-3)$) {$pq$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The picture:
[image]

Comment: have a look at the first two edges -- the code `[ pos=0.48,edge label=\scriptsize A]` is used to define the position (midway), in reduced font size(scriptsize) -- please see the answer below -- the same can be replicated for the other nodes

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I was wondering about the loop above the node `3`. Is there any similar way to add a label, there?

Comment: please see the edit below -- for all the loops -- I have also added an edit to add label for only one loop

Comment: would you like to accept and upvote the answer now

Comment: Answer accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=30, in=155}] {
    (bn-1-1) ->[ pos=0.48,edge label=\scriptsize A] (bn-1-2) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-8)
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=210, in=335}] {
    (bn-1-8) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-2) ->[pos=0.48,edge label=\scriptsize B] (bn-1-1)
  };
```

**and for the loops**

```
  \foreach \x in {1,...,8}
    \path[->,>=Latex]
      (bn-1-\x) edge [out=110,in=70,looseness=12] node[yshift=-5pt,  above, label=\scriptsize bn-1-\x] {} (bn-1-\x);
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows.meta,
    calc,
    graphs,
    matrix,
    positioning,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (bn) [matrix of nodes, column sep=14mm, row sep=1mm, nodes={draw, circle, fill=white, very thick, minimum width=8mm}]
  {
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=30, in=155}] {
    (bn-1-1) ->[ pos=0.48,edge label=\scriptsize A] (bn-1-2) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-8)
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=210, in=335}] {
    (bn-1-8) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-2) ->[pos=0.48,edge label=\scriptsize B] (bn-1-1)
  };
  \foreach \x in {1,...,8}
    \path[->,>=Latex]
      (bn-1-\x) edge [out=110,in=70,looseness=12] node[yshift=-5pt,  above, label=\scriptsize bn-1-\x] {} (bn-1-\x);

  % New labels
%  \node (pnq) at ([yshift=7.5mm]$(bn-1-3)!0.5!(bn-1-4)$) {$p(1-q)$};
%  \node (npq) at ([yshift=-7.5mm]$(bn-1-3)!0.5!(bn-1-2)$) {$q(1-p)$};
%  \node (npq) at ([yshift=16.5mm]$(bn-1-3)!0.5!(bn-1-3)$) {$pq$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT add label to single loop**

**MWE**

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows.meta,
    calc,
    graphs,
    matrix,
    positioning,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (bn) [matrix of nodes, column sep=14mm, row sep=1mm, nodes={draw, circle, fill=white, very thick, minimum width=8mm}]
  {
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=30, in=155}] {
    (bn-1-1) ->[ pos=0.48,edge label=\scriptsize A] (bn-1-2) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-8)
  };
  \graph[edges={>=Latex, semithick, color=black, out=210, in=335}] {
    (bn-1-8) -> (bn-1-7) -> (bn-1-6) -> (bn-1-5) -> (bn-1-4) -> (bn-1-3) -> (bn-1-2) ->[pos=0.48,edge label=\scriptsize B] (bn-1-1)
  };
  \foreach \x in {1,2,4,5,6,7,8}
    \path[->,>=Latex]
      (bn-1-\x) edge [out=110,in=70,looseness=12] node[] {} (bn-1-\x);


\foreach \x in {3}
\path[->,>=Latex]
(bn-1-\x) edge [out=110,in=70,looseness=12] node[yshift=-5pt,  above, label=\scriptsize pq] {} (bn-1-\x);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]